# Script @php artisan statamic:install --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I installed 1 source laravel 10 from github and ran composer update. Then I got an error and couldn't find a solution.

```
 composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan statamic:install --ansi

   ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "statamic" namespace.

Script @php artisan statamic:install --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I tried editing in composer.json file but it doesn't work

```
"extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "10.x-dev"
        },
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/dusk"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Have you installed statamic with composer? It's not an automatic part of Laravel

Comment: "There are no commands defined in the "statamic" namespace." - did you read that message? Also, I would assume that this is not a problem with Composer itself?